# Speed up Rtexttools with parallel / foreach

Tags: r, text-mining, random-forest, doparallel

I'm trying to classify about 10.000 documents using the RTexttools package. When I'm calculating a Random Forest train model the proces consumes a lot of time (CPU and memory).
I work on a machine with 4 cores and 4GB of ram. However, I can see that my R-session only uses 1 core for execution.
I'v read some documentation of foreach and doparallel, but I have trouble relating this to textmining. 
Say I want to speed up the following command (which currently takes more than 120 minutes):

```
library(RTextTools)
library(tm)
data <- read.csv2(file.choose(), header = T, sep = ";")
colnames(data) <-c("Text","Sentiment")
doc_matrix <-
  create_matrix(
    data$Text,
    language = "russian",
    removeNumbers = TRUE,
    stemWords = TRUE,
    removeSparseTerms = .998
  )
container <-
  create_container(
    doc_matrix,
    data$Sentiment,
    trainSize = 1:1000,
    testSize = 1001:2165,
    virgin = FALSE
  )
RF <- train_model(container,"RF")
```

Is there a way to speed up this proces by using parallelization?
If I just use

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)
```

before the train model calculation it won't help much.

Comment: Read the documentation for RTexttools package. If parallelisation isn't mentioned, then you can't. Foreach can be implemented only when you define the loops. Check the random forest model in xgboost and h2o packages for parallelisation.

Comment: Yep, `xgboost` seems to be a good alternative: https://www.r-bloggers.com/goodreads-machine-learning-part-3/ I'll try it.